# can apache and rails run on the same server in different directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

is there any special configuration that needs to occur to make this happen?

currently my setup is such that the folder `rails/wiki`, where I installed all my rails stuff and all the config files live, it is a subdirectory of `/var/www/html`, is that alright?

instead of the server landing page, it's just the folder structure:

http://btwnthelin.es/rails/wiki/
.

The main component `/var/www/html` has my apache stuff:

http://btwnthelin.es/

and that works fine.

The server is running on port 3000, I thought I could access it by 
`http://btwnthelin.es:3000` but that results in a 404 error.

---

**development.log**

```
[1m[36m (3.3ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL) [0m
[1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  select sqlite_version(*)
[1m[36m (2.3ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m
[1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateArticles (20150511093446)
[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
[1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "articles" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar, "content" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) 
[1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES (?)[0m  [["version", "20150511093446"]]
[1m[35m (2.5ms)[0m  commit transaction
[1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
[1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
[1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Comment: do you to run http://btwnthelin.es on http://btwnthelin.es:3000?

Comment: Are you using passenger?

Comment: What I understand from your problem is you are trying to run rails application using webrick on the server where apache is already running on port 80. If you are asking for this then yes you can run both webrick and apache from same server. Rick answered about adding localhost to hosts file. I think this will work for you. If not please share your webrick logs.

Comment: @rick I'm not sure about that. I think, as railites said I have apache running on 80 and that's what btwnthelin.es is running on

Comment: @FrederickCheung what is a passenger?

Comment: @railites it finally didn't work. but I can't find `webrick logs` where is that located? I found `development.log` in the folder `logs` but nothin else was there

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Passenger is an application server and Apache is a webserver. For running any web application we need both application and webserver. Webrick server shipped with rails, by default works as both webserver and application server. Can you show us development log and configuration you are using to run your rails application.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English without passenger Apache doesn't know what rails apps are. It's not the only way to serve a rails app (you can use Apache as a proxy to unicorn, puma etc) but it's an easy and solid performer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/etc/hosts` text file add this,

```
127.0.0.1 btwnthelin.es
```

Comment: I tried that, but nothing seemed to happen, the other things there were `127.0.0.1 btwnthelin.es    127.0.0.1 btwnthelin.es   ` and I've just added, according to your suggestion `127.0.0.1 btwnthelin.es`

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Have you tried to access this like, http://btwnthelin.es:3000    ?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work, maybe I need to install passenger or something first

Comment: @Frederick is right. Please look into this https://www.phusionpassenger.com/ or you can also follow this step by step http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/research/hmtl/wp/index.php/rvm-ruby-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: do you think [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6) is good?

Comment: I installed passenger, and everything seems good. i restarted my apache server, and i restarted the rails server but still i don't see that landing page. so i need to reinstall rails after installing passenger?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Have to set  Apache’s config file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) and added virtual host section ? Please check all configuration and path that you set in this file and don't forgot to restart Apache server after doing any changes